# How to check that my elastic search is up or not if its running in an ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elasticsearch-5

I have setup an elastic search version 6.5+ in an EC2 machine and when i do curl localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty it returns me value but its when i will do it on google chrome with ec2instance public ip it will not result me data and i get that because i have not bind my network host to run on 0.0.0.0 . and i don't want to do that because it will expose my data . Now my spring boot application is running on a beanstalk instance and if i try to connect it from there to elastic search instance it still doesn't work . so i put the beanstalk public ip to network host still it does not work and still its not a viable solution as my beanstalk ip can change based on autoscaling . So whats the correct way to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

You may use a reverse proxy in front of your elasticsearch instance to allow only specific request (/_cluster/health?pretty) from your public IP and all requests only from another specific IP using the virtual servers feature. Or you may also implement 'Basic Auth' to allow all requests, exposing the elasticsearch instance on public IP. Just keep in mind to have your reverse proxy in the same AWS region as the elasticsearch instance and use the private IP/DNS in your reverse proxy to communicate with the elasticsearch instance.
Don't forget to check for the added latency and further optimizations you may utilize in this process like setting keep alive connections and request limits etc.

Comment: What if i give my beanstalk instance public ip to access the elastic search instance

Comment: Is there any way to configure elastic beanstalk url in the security group of that instance so that it allows traffic from that ip